# Can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to create Excel file on the system where Microsoft Office pack is not installed?

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio-2010, com

I am adding `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` from the .net tab of the Add Reference option of Visual Studio to create Excel file. Everything is working fine and I am getting quite good and fast Excel reports.

Now my only concern is that can I use this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in the System where Microsoft office Pack is not installed. Will I be able to create an Excel file in this condition?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i use this Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the System where
>   Microsoft office Pack is not installed.Will i be able to create Excel
>   in this condition ?

No. Office would have to be installed.

Instead, use [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) (it's free):

> Create advanced Excel 2007/2010 spreadsheets on the server. EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files
>   using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

I've used EPPlus in several projects and it works well.

Comment: Can i export dataGridView from Winform app into .Excel using EPPLus

Comment: You can do pretty much anything. It's code that you write and have control over it's actions!